# clean way to make array a 2d array

Tags: perl

Looking for a cleaner (possibly one liner) way to write the following

```
my $spec_2d = ( );
foreach ( @spec ) {
  $spec_2d[$_][0] = $spec[$_];
}
@spec = @spec_2d;
```

Basically I'm making an array an array of arrays

Answer (score 2):

```
@spec_2d[@spec] = map [ $spec[$_] ], @spec;
```

but judging from the subject I think you want this,

```
my @spec_2d = map [ $_ ], @spec;
```